# Convert Scala Map to Json in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, scala, playframework

Trying to convert:

```
Map(1416479696353 -> Map(name -> You,savePoint -> 4),
1416479788969 -> Map(name -> You, savePoint -> 9),
1416479801372 -> Map(name -> govind,savePoint -> 10))
```

into JavaScript `json` by:

```
<script>
var info=@Json.toJson(data.toMap)
</script>
```

but giving me this error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id

var info={&quot;1416479696353&quot;:{&quot;name&qu
----------^
```

How to get in the correct manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the HTML, i.e.:

```
<script>
    var info=@Html(Json.toJson(data.toMap));
</script>
```